# Consonants stuck in Pig Latin

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having problem with my codes here. When I input ONLY consonants, the program will stuck. But when I input a mix consonants and vowel, it run as expected.

For example:

1. apple --> appleway
2. is --> isway
3. a --> away
4. scratch --> atchscray
5. b --> stuck like nothing happen

Appreciate if you could assist me on this. Thank you.

```
while True:         

    word = input("Enter a word ('quit' to quit): ")
    ignoreCase = "quit"           
    vowels = "aeiou"

    if word.lower() == ignoreCase.lower(): 
      break

    elif word == "":               
         print("Can't convert empty string.  Try again.")

    for index,c in enumerate(word.lower()):  

      if c in vowels:

         print(word.lower()[0:] + "way".lower()) 
         break

      elif vowels:    #No vowel statement
         while word.lower()[0] not in vowels:
          word = word.lower()[1:] + word.lower()[0] 
         print(word.lower() + "ay".lower())
         break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution (without modifying your code too much) is to check for the very special case when a word has no vowels.

```
ignoreCase = "quit"
vowels = "aeiou"

while True:
    # Get word and convert to lower case
    word = input("Enter a word ('quit' to quit): ").lower()

    if word == ignoreCase: 
        break
    elif word == "":               
        print("Can't convert empty string.  Try again.")
    else:
        # Starts with a vowel
        if word[0] in vowels:
            print(word + "way") 

        # Starts with a consonant
        else:
            # Only run loop if word has vowels
            if any(char in vowels for char in word):
                while word[0] not in vowels:
                   word = word[1:] + word[0] 
            print(word + "ay")
```

Comment: Hi @Johnny, thank you for the codes. But is it possible to include "has no vowels" into #Start With A Consonant code? I've tried modifying the codes but no luck.

Comment: Do you mean to incorporate it into `while word[0] not in vowels:`?

Comment: yes, since I need no vowel string to print with "ay" at the end. For example:

1. d ---> day
2. scratch ----> atchscray

Comment: Ok. Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! So "the loop if word has vowels" is the main key. Appreciate it :)